# SSIS reading data from a view

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have recently encountered this problem wherein when I am trying to load data from a view(view has join on 3 different tables) to a table, I see that the reading from source pauses for a minute and continues the load and after loading x number of records it again pauses for a while and then continues.
this are my settings of 
Default BufferSize:104857600(100MB)
DefaultBufferMaxRows: 2700(my row size 39417 bytes based on dataTypes)

right now I am not loading any data to destination to check why reading goes into a pause state, I am using a rowcount transformation as destination.
in my case data reading happens continuously for 1024580 records pauses for approx 1min and then continues till 2067449 and then pauses for a 1min and then continues till 3110368 and this happens till the load is complete.
number of rows in input is approx 300Million.

Comment: I don't actually see a question up there.

Comment: Smells like an issue with the source system as opposed to SSIS

Comment: try to read it without a view. Can you make the joins yourself? Sometimes views can be broken especially if you changed server version.

Comment: plaidDK; tried using by making joins in the OledbSource instead of view, same result, it pauses for every 1M approx for around 50sec and then continues.

Comment: @TabAlleman: question is why the oledbsource pauses everytime? is it because of my incorrect Defaultbuffersize and Maxbuffer settings ? or is it pausing to fetch the rows for tables because of the join-I dont think this it the reason ?it pauses approx for 50sec for every 1Million and I have 300M to load so, 50*300 there is approx 15000sec which is 4hrs pause time, if I can avoid this I can reduce 4hrs of load time.

Comment: set defaultbuffermaxrows to 200000  and try to set defaultbuffersize 30485760 but i guess it also happens on the server side it self? Then it cannot be a ssis issue. Are u reading through linked server?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to monitor server resources during the execution?   If so, what did you find?

Comment: How much ram does the machine you're running the package on have? What is its memory usage at "idle" and what is it when the package is running? It sounds like it's loading as much data as it can into memory, processing it, and then loading more. Also, running the package through the UI is going to be much slower than running via SQL Agent Job or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check your local Temp folder (run %temp%) and see if SSIS creates temp files. If that's the case, you need to do some hack solution which breaks down rows by 8MB chuncks and then recreate it back together.
This is old DTS model that does not process blob data well in memory (pretty much anything over 8MB)